# Techniques to reduce data harvesting from AJAX/JSON services

Tags: ajax, security, web-services, json

I was wondering if anyone had come across any techniques to reduce the chances of data exposed through JSON type services on the server (intended to supply AJAX functions) from being harvested by external agents.

It seems to me that the problem is not so difficult if you had say a Flash client consuming the data.  Then you could send encrypted data to the client, which would know how to decrypt it.  The same method seems impossible with AJAX though, due to the open nature of the Javascript source.

Has anybody implemented a clever technique here?

Whatever the method, it should still allow a genuine AJAX function to consume the data.

Note that I'm not really talking about protecting 'sensitive' information here, the odd record leaking out is not a problem.  Rather I am thinking about stopping a situation where the whole DB is hoovered up by bots (either in one go, or gradually over time).

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I would like to clear on this:

> It seems to me that the problem is not
>   so difficult if you had say a Flash
>   client consuming the data. Then you
>   could send encrypted data to the
>   client, which would know how to
>   decrypt it. The same method seems
>   impossible with AJAX though, due to
>   the open nature of the Javascrip
>   source.

It will be pretty obvious the information is being sent encrypted to the flash client & it won't be that hard for the attacker to find out from your flash compiled program what's being used for this - replicate & get all that data.

If the data does happens to have the value you are thinking, you can count on the above.

**If this is public information, embrace that & don't combat it - instead find ways to capitalize on it.**

If this is information that you are only exposing to a set of users, make sure you have the corresponding authentication / secure communication. Track usage as others have said, and have measures that act on it,

Comment: "If this is public information, embrace that & don't combat it - instead find ways to capitalize on it." +1

Comment: Yup, that sentence alone deserves a +1.

Answer (score 7):

The first thing to prevent bots from stealing your data is not technological, it's legal.  First, make sure you have the right language in your site's Terms of Use that what you're trying to prevent is actually disallowed and defensible from a legal standpoint.  Second, make sure you design your technical strategy with legal issues in mind.  For example, in the US, if you put data behind an authentication barrier and an attacker steals it, it's likely a [violation of the DMCA law](http://www.chillingeffects.org/anticircumvention/faq.cgi).  Third, find a lawyer who can advise you on IP and DMCA issues... nice folks on StackOverflow aren't enough. :-)

Now, about the technology:

A reasonable solution is to require that users be authenticated before they can get access to your sensitive Ajax calls.  This allows you to simply monitor per-user usage of your Ajax calls and (manually or automatically) cancel the account of any user who makes too many requests in a particular time period. (or too many total requests, if you're trying to defend against a trickle approach).

This approach of course is vulnerable to sophisticated bots who automatically sign up new "users", but with a reasonably good CAPTCHA implementation, it's quite hard to build this kind of bot. (see "circumvention" section at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA)

If you are trying to protect *public* data (no authentication) then your options are much more limited.  As other answers noted, you can try IP-address-based limits (and run afoul of large corporate proxy users) but sophisticated attackers can get around this by distributing the load.  There's also likley sophisticated software which watches things like request timing, request patterns, etc. and tries to spot bots. Poker sites, for example, spend a lot of time on this. But don't expect these kinds of systems to be cheap.  One easy thing you can do is to mine your web logs (e.g. using [Splunk](http://splunk.com)) and find the top N IP addresses hitting your site, and then do a reverse-IP lookup on them. Some will be legitimate corporate or ISP proxies. But if you recognize a compeitor's domain name among the list, you can block their domain or follow up with your lawyers.

In addition to pre-theft defense, you might also want to think about inserting a "honey pot": deliberately fake information that you can track later.  This is how, for example, maps manufacturers catch plaigarism: they insert a fake street in their maps and see which other maps show the same fake street.  While this doesn't prevent determined folks from sucking out all your data, it does let you find out later who's re-using your data.  This can be done by embedding unique text strings in your text output, and then searching for those strings on Google later (assuming your data is re-usable on another public website). If your data is HTML or images, you can include an image which points back to your site, and you can track who is downloading it, and look for patterns you can use to bust the freeloaders.

Note that the javascript encryption approach noted in one of the other answers won't work for non-authenticated sessions-- an attacker can simply download the javascript and run it just like a regular browser would. Moral of the story: public data is essentially indefensible.  If you want to keep data protected, put it behind an authentication barrier.

This is obvious, but if your data is publicly searchable by search engines, you'll both need a non-AJAX solution for them (Google won't read your ajax data!) and you'll want to mark those pages [NOARCHIVE](http://www.ezau.com/latest/articles/no-archive.shtml) so your data doesn't show up in Google's cache.  You'll also probably want a white list of search engine crawler IP addreses which you allow into your search-engine-crawlable pages (you can work with Google, Bing, Yahoo, etc. to get these), otherwise malicious bots could simply impersonate Google and get your data.

In conclusion, I want to echo @kdgregory above: make sure that the threat is real enough that it's worth the effort required.  Many companies overestimate the interest that other people (both legitimate customers and nefarious actors) have in their business.  It might be that yours is an oddball case where you have particularly important data, it's particularly valuable to obtain, it must be publicly accessible without authentication, and your legal recourses will be limited if someone steals your data.  But all those together is admittedly an unusual case.

P.S. - another way to think about this problem which may or may not apply in your case. Sometimes it's easier to change how your data works which obviates securing it. For example, can you tie your data in some way to a service on your site so that the data isn't very useful unless it's being used in conjunction with your code. Or can you embed advertising in it, so that wherever it's shown you get paid?  And so on. I don't know if any of these mitigations apply to your case, but many businesses have found ways to give stuff away for free on the Internet (and encourage rather than prevent wide re-distribution) and still make money, so a hybrid free/pay strategy may (or may not) be possible in your case.

Comment: It is a fine line between being extremely offensive to the technical community by citing legal frameworks and attempting to protect the developer. It is like the recording industry encouraging music distribution in the 80s and then turning around and labelling an entire generation as lawbreakers in the 2000s when user-distribution techniques become lossless. If you publish public data you don't want others to view then lock it down - don't go chasing after people with terms and conditions after the fact.

Comment: I agree, the law is not an excuse for not figuring out good technical solutions. I actually had a specific scenario in mind with my "legal" suggestion: if a determined, well-funded competitor (not lots of individual users) decides to steal all your data, regardless of whatever technical roadblocks you put up, it would be bad if you didn't have any legal leverage to get them to stop.  I didn't mean to endorse the record industry's approach to this problem, or any similar thing-- sorry if I came across this way.

Comment: Just to let you know - I would have marked this as the accepted answer, but unfortunately was away from computer at the end of bounty.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an internal Memcached box, you could consider using a technique where you create an entry for each IP that hits your server with an hour expiration. Then increment that value each time the IP hits your AJAX endpoint. If the value gets over a particular threshold, fry the connection. If the value expires in Memcached, you know it isn't getting "hoovered away".

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a concrete answer with a proof of concept, but maybe a starting point for you.  You could create a javascript function that provides encryption/decryption functions.  The javascript would need to be built dynamically, and you would include an encryption key that is unique to the session.  On the server side, you'd have an encryption service that uses the key from the session to encrypt your JSON before delivering it.

This would at least prevent someone from listening to your web traffic, pulling information out of your database.

I'm with kdgergory though, it sounds like your data is too open.

Answer (score 1):

Some techniques are listed in [Further thoughts on hindering screen scraping](http://blog.screen-scraper.com/2009/08/17/further-thoughts-on-hindering-screen-scraping/).

If you use PHP, [Bad behavior](http://www.bad-behavior.ioerror.us/) is a nice tool to help. If you don't use PHP, it can give some ideas on how to filter (see [How it works](http://www.bad-behavior.ioerror.us/documentation/how-it-works/) page).

[Incredibill's blog](http://incredibill.blogspot.com/) is giving nice tips, lists of User-agents/IP ranges to block, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Here are a variety of suggestions:

1. Issue tokens required for redemption along with each AJAX request.  Expire the tokens.
2. Track how many queries are coming from each client, and throttle excessive usage based on expected normal usage of your site.
3. Look for patterns in usage such as sequential queries, spikes in requests, or queries that occur faster than a human could conduct.
4. Check user-agents.  Many bots don't completely replicate the user agent info of a browser, and you can eliminate programatic scraping of your data using this method.
5. Change the front-end component of your website to redirect to a captcha (or some other human verifying mechanism) once a request threshold is exceeded.
6. Modify your logic so the respsonse data is returned in a few different ways to complicate the code required to parse.
7. Obsfucate your client-side javascript.
8. Block IPs of offending clients.

Answer (score 0):

Bots usually doesn't parse Javascript, so your ajax code won't be instantly executed. And if they even do, bots usually doesn't maintain sessions/cookies as well. Knowing that, you could reject the request if it is invoked without a valid session/cookie (which is obviously set on the server side beforehand by the request on the parent page).

This does not protect you from human hazard though. The safest way is to restrict access to users with a login/password. If that is not your intent, well, then you have to live with the fact that it's a **public** application. You could of course scan logs and maintian blacklists with IP addresses and useragents, but that goes extreme.